# PHP HTML display img src using output buffer - end up with broken image

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a script that takes two png images, one is a watermark and the other one is a source image. What the code will do is it will call on a function that does an imagecopy and blend the two images into one, and display on the browser. However, I always end up with a broken image.

I don't want to save the image, I just want the browser to display the source image with the watermark on. 
I have also checked the file permission, the function itself works fine when it's alone. The correct image is showing using imagepng

Below is my testing code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
showimage();
$image = ob_get_contents();
$data = base64_encode($image);
ob_clean();

echo "<h1> hello </h1>";
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . $data . "'/>";

function showimage() {
    $target_dir = "./uploads/";
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($target_dir.'watermark.png');
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng($target_dir.'greenblobburnt.png');

    imagealphablending($dest, true);
    imagealphablending($src, true);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);
    imagesavealpha($src, true);
    imagecopy ($dest,$src, 5, imagesy($dest) - (imagesy($src)+5), 0, 0,imagesx($src),imagesy($src));
    imagealphablending($dest, true);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);
    // Output and free from memory
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest);
    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
}
?>
```

Comment: You misunderstand --- you can not output html with an img tag and also include the image data in the src.  The src expects a url.  If your code simply was to return the image data without the html, then you can have seperate markup that references that script as the src= url.

Comment: @gview suggest you read up on data URIs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: Get rid of the `header('Content-Type: image/png');` line, or the browser will think you're serving an image instead of HTML. It will try to render it and fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to mix html-with-image-inlined together with raw image binary, and thanks to that header() call, you're telling the browser "this is a png image", when it's actually html+raw png binary concatenated. then the browser try to render this mess, the png renderer fails, and you get the "corrupt image" error.

try to get rid of the html output, and the output buffer, aka

```
echo "<h1> hello </h1>";
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . $data . "'/>";
```

and the

```
ob_start(); $image = ob_get_contents();ob_clean();
```

remove it. do you still get a corrupted image error?

Comment: the code i posted is a test snippet of a image gallery site that I am trying to achieve. I want to display the image with a watermark on using the img src tag. Is there not a workaround with this?

Comment: Are you familiar with [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)? There's nothing wrong with what they're trying to do, aside from the header issue. I suspect removing `header('Content-Type: image/png');` will fix things up nicely.

Comment: Wow, that actually solves my problem and all of my images are displaying correctly somehow.  Why is the line header causing the issue? I am wondering if you also update your answer so people don't downvote your answer. I don't have enough reputations to do upvotes on the site yet.